# How can I make the space above the corners of the image transparent?

Tags: android

I have a linear layout that uses all the width and height of the screen. Below is the code with which I set the background of the linear layout. But I do not how to make the space above the corners transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#90FFFFFF"
          android:endColor="#50000000"
          android:centerColor="#70990000"
          android:angle="180"/>
              <corners android:radius="10dip/>
              <stroke android:width="3dip"
                 android:color="#990000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` is inside an other layout. Isn't the outer layout's color is displayed above the corners?

Comment: Hi,I am using only one linear layout . i think i can do this by using two linear layout and space above the corner will then take the color of parent layout. is there any effective solution for it?

Comment: The application has a background by default (white/black i don't remember). Maybe try to override that color, or use 2 layouts yours inside the new one.